# Dúvida Criteria

Tags: java, criteria

Eu consigo fazer um critéria com uma entidade que não esteja mapeada em outra entidade? Ou tenho que usar query nativa para fazer essa consulta?

Tenho uma entidade usuario e outra produto mas não tenho relacionamento de produto com usuário mas tenho que trazer o nome do usuario na query de produto sendo que no usuario existe so uma variável idProduto sem relacionamento.

Exemplo:

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "DCF_USUARIOS")
    public class UsuarioTO{


            @Id
            @Column(name = "id")
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            private Long id;

         @Column(name = "nome_usuario")
            private String nomeUsuario;


            @Column(name = "id_produto")
            private Long idProduto;
        }

        @Entity
        @Table(name = "DCF_PRODUTO")
        public class ProdutoTO{


            @Id
            @Column(name = "id")
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            private Long  id;

        }
```

**Então quero fazer uma criteria em produto, mas preciso trazer o nome do usuário que tenha o id do produto gravado na entidade sendo que não estão relacionados um com outro.
Teria como fazer com criterio ou tenho que fazer uma nativeQuery com Join entre as duas tabelas?**